# Как найти кратчайшый путь от заданой вершины ко всем другим?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, графы, динамическое-программирование

Дано n точек, и координату вершины с какой начинаем, найти кратчайший путь, для обхода всех точек от заданой, и также вернутся назад к ней.Так званая задача о коммивояжёрe.Это довольно легко сделать за сложность O(n!) просто генерируя все перестановки длины n и сумировать расстояния, но ето очень медленно. Буду очень благодарен коду на языке С++, Python, Paskal или идею для решения.

```
Начинаем в точке с координатами (0,0)

Тест:
    N - 3
    1   4
    -2  7
    -1 -1
Вывод: 
    4.4605544059

Ограничения:
    n = 20
    -1000 <= x, y <= 1000
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, для 20 вершин полным перебором уже никак не решить.
Но поскольку у вас точки на плоскости - для них справедливо неравенство треугольника, т.е. что путь AB будет не длиннее пути ACB - существует приближенный полиномиальный алгоритм, дающий решение, которое не более чем в 2 раза хуже оптимального.

Строится полный граф с точками как вершинами, и ребрами с весами, равными расстояниям.  Выбирается произвольная вершина в качестве корневой, и с помощью алгоритма Прима строится минимальное остовное дерево с этим корнем. Пусть H - список вершин, упорядоченный в соответствии с моментом первого посещения при обходе получившегося дерева в прямом порядке. Все, искомое приближенное решение - гамильтонов цикл H.

Подробнее см. в книге *Алгоритмы. Построение и анализ* Кормена-Лейзерсона-Ривеста-Штайна.

Обычно неплохой результат для точек на плоскости дает поиск минимального битонического маршрута - т.е. маршрута, который идет от крайней левой точки в крайнюю правую, и только вправо, а потом назад - и уже только влево. См. ту же книгу.

Еще вариант - метод ветвлений с отсечениями. Выбираете одну вершину и начинаете строить перебором пути, все время фиксируя минимальный цикл. Как только видите, что очередной путь не приведет к меньшей длине, чем уже достигнута - отбрасываете все пути с уже пройденным началом. При определенном везении можно получить оптимальное решение за вполне реальное время.

Но раз у вас в тегах - динамическое программирование, рекомендовал бы, например, эту статью - [Динамическое программирование для задачи коммивояжера](https://cyberleninka.ru/article/v/dinamicheskoe-programmirovanie-dlya-zadachi-kommivoyazhera), описывать которую здесь не получится за отсутствием места на полях (с) Ферма :), или глянуть в [Википедию](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0_%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%B6%D1%91%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). А [вот тут](https://compscicenter.ru/media/course_class_attachments/20171126_tsp_csclub.pdf) имеется даже код на Питоне...